# How to use string values for Y-Axis in xlLine ChartType

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-interop

I need to generate some line charts using excel.interop and I would like to set text for the Y-Axis values.

```
Dictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string, int>();
data.Add("abc", 1);
data.Add("def", 2);
data.Add("ghi", 3);
data.Add("jkl", 4);
data.Add("mno", 5);

var application = new excel.Application();
var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(docName);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as excel.Worksheet;
var charts = worksheet.ChartObjects() as excel.ChartObjects;
var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300);
var chart = chartObject.Chart;
chart.ChartType = excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
chart.Location(excel.XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, worksheetName);
var seriesCollection = (excel.SeriesCollection)chart.SeriesCollection();
var series = seriesCollection.NewSeries();

series.Values = data.Keys.ToArray();
series.XValues = data.Values.ToArray();

series.Name = "test";

workbook.Save();
```

But this is my result (series.Values contains only 0'values).

[image: Excel output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use text for the X-Axis?

```
        //series.Values = data.Keys.ToArray();
        //series.XValues = data.Values.ToArray();

        series.XValues = data.Keys.ToArray();
        series.Values = data.Values.ToArray();
```

[image]

Or perhaps you could use a bar chart:

[image]

Comment: I know I can use text for X-axis. My question is about the Y-axis. In case I have some texts with an associated value, but I need to display the text instead.

Comment: That would be possible, for instance, in a range bar chart, but not line chart. Could you manually build a line chart with strings in the Y-Axis, within Excel itself?

Comment: You're right. A line chart is not the best display option for my example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the green check !